# Android studios doesn't update app on mobile device

Tags: android, adb

My problem is that when I ran my app and use my mobile device the app isn't updated with any of the changes I've made to the code. I've checked the 'Android Device Monitor' and it sees my phone. Yesterday I downloaded 'universal adb driver' because I was trying to print a logcat. I thought that downloading this driver despite already having USB google driver might have caused the issuse. I've uninstalled univeral adb driver but the problem persists. Can anybody help me

Comment: If it is uncertain the the IDE is doing what you ask, trying using the command line to uninstall the original apk build and install the new build.  At the least you will get more informative error messages and a chance to see them. See the adb documentation.

Answer (score 7):

I know I am late, but if anyone else comes here, run `Build`>`Clean project`.
It's a bug in Android studio. That crap is ancient, and still not fixed.

Comment: It's really unbelievable! Android Studio is probably one of the worst projects Google has ever released... I wonder if some involved people there got fired...

Comment: Neither cleaning nor rebuilding (if Gradle works in a similar way to cmake rebuild should also trigger a cleanup of the old stuff) work for me using the latest version of studio.

Comment: Hello, I want to report that today, nov 2020,  this bug is still alive, up and running. Android Studio version 4.1, gradle version 6.7.

Answer (score 1):

You need to go to `Run > Edit configurations...` and disable the "Allow parallel run" checkbox at the right top corner of that window, it will even solve the problem that your activity don't run after app build. It's only one solution which was helped to me.

Answer (score -1):

Simply uninstall the application from your mobile device and then run your app again with your device connected and make sure to select the correct device when Android Studio prompts you to.

Answer (score -1):

Try Re-build the gradle. I should work for you. Sometimes if the build id processing and your usb cable is removed or not connected properly, there might be chance to get this issue.

Also, Check the error logs in the studio. They will tell you what exactly you need to do.