# Ionic 4 project - Android studio & ADB doesn't update with changes in code

Tags: android, android-studio, ionic-framework, adb, ionic4

I have an Ionic 4 mobile app project and have been previously been testing with with ADB with Android Studio. I can successfully run/build and install onto my android device. However, no changes I make in the code take affect when I view the app on my device.

**This link was the closest I could find to my issue:** [Android studios doesn't update app on mobile device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29008761/android-studios-doesn)'t-update-app-on-mobile-device/38919601

I have tried to *Build > Clean Project* in Android Studio but it hasn't worked for me.

This is my first question on here so any tips on how to improve my ability to ask would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your suggested link having a solution. Try Re-build the Gradle.
Do `build->Rebuild project` then run it.

To be sure you are on right project :).

Comment: Thanks for the reply - turns out I needed to run an `ionic build` as well

Comment: Thanks @thegoat for your valuable response. Can you please also accept this as the proper answer?

Answer (score 1):

I needed to run an `ionic build` before running `npx cap add android` and `npx cap open android`